# Changing Project Build from 4.3 to 2.2 Changes Resource Access

Tags: android, resources

I've developed a simple app using a 4.3 app build. Everything works fine on the emulator.
Once I transferred it to my phone vie email (i can't debug on phone as USB doesnt work anymore) the app crashed (this isn't what the question is about).

Doing some reasearch I found on this page:

https://cloud.testdroid.com/web/devices#view=LIST&name=

that my phone (Samsung Infuse) runs 2.2.1 with an API level of 8.

Going into project properties, I changed the Android Project Build Targe to "2.2".

HOWEVER, upon going back into my code I know have errors with the followins sort of code:

```
findViewById(R.id.textName)
```

I can still use "R.id" and "R.drawable", however I get a totally set of different resources.

So my questions are these:

```
1) what happened?
2) what resources am I seeing?
3) how do I access my original resources?
4) what do I need to be considering if I want this app to work on the newest phones as well as the older phones? (Im a bit worried)
```

Thank you for your help

Comment: why are you changing the project target? just set it to 4.3 and the minimum target as 2.2

Comment: fyi, instead of email, you could try [AirDroid](http://airdroid.com/)

Answer (score 1):

You could ensure that your AndroidManifest.xml file has the following line:

```
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8" android:targetSdkVersion="18"/>
```

The target version is not so critical at this point, since you need to **make sure** that your minSdkVersion matches your phone (or lower) in order to work.

**Also**, you may need to do a rebuild of your project to ensure that your resources (R) file is available in your class file(s). If it is not showing, then you may need to import it explicitly, such as:

```
import com.your.app.pkg.R;
```

Comment: the import statement worked... it had been changed to Android.R
Im gonna hold off on closing out the question though as I'm still intereseted in the other parts of the question. Thank you!